# No SQL Server instances show in upgrade setup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to upgrade SQL Server 2005 sp4 to SQL Server 2008 R2. However on the upgrade wizard doesn't show me any instances to upgrade. Any ideas?

The instance is there just fine.  I can connect via sql mgmt studio.

Comment: Possible permissions issue? Can you launch the upgrade advisor with an account you know has access to the instance?

Comment: What *edition* is already present, and what *edition* are you trying to install?

Comment: Standard to Standard.

Comment: @SQLRockstar have full sysadmin to the instance.

Comment: And they're both 64-bit?

Comment: Hmmm....missing a file? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4b7cce6e-df1c-4d6c-b3c0-154a86286bad/select-instance-is-not-available-when-upgrade-to-sql-2008-r2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to upgrade SQL Express 2014 to 2016, as mentioned by @SQLRockstar for me the problem was missing SQL msi files in C:\Windows\Installer directory, so I restored msi cache by using [FixMissingMSI](https://github.com/suyouquan/SQLSetupTools?tab=readme-ov-file#fixmissingmsi-version-22) tool. It is mentioned in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/install/windows/restore-missing-windows-installer-cache-files) together with other ways to fix that problem. After that installer was able to see my instances and upgrade them.